# cygwin compiled binaries blocked by Antiviruses like Norton, Kaspersky etc

Tags: cygwin

I have compiled a linux based code to windows using Cygwin, and packaged it as a part of an Adobe AIR exe. The AIR application gets installed and everything is fine, until the time  the product internally executes the C++ based binaries compiled. When that happens, the various antiviruses promptly give the warning that the C++ binary is not trusted and is blocked. Any comments on how to prevent this would be really helpful.

Comment: Bit off-topic, but are you running multiple anti-viruses?  That's typically regarded as a bad thing...

Comment: What exactly is getting flagged? What does "not trusted" mean for that particular AV? You'd better check that, and take it up with the AV vendor...

Answer (score 0):

On most anti-virus systems I have used (YMMV), you can exempt either files or directories from anti-virus software actions.